# Prevent client to use SSL Session reuse

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, session-reuse

Due to some restraints in the network infrastructure(load balancing) we have to switch off SSL Session reuse for some specific traffic.

Our client created in C# .Net is sending an SOAP v1.1 over SSL with an Client Certificate but I looking to see that we can prevent trying to use SSL session reuse (This only happens with Win 8 and Win 10 clients).

Can this be disabled from within our client without need to reconfigure on OS level as in the registry?

> [HttpWebRequest.ClientCertificates Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.clientcertificates.aspx)
>
> INFO
>
> The Framework caches SSL sessions as they are created and attempts to
>   reuse a cached session for a new request, if possible. When attempting
>   to reuse an SSL session, the Framework uses the first element of
>   ClientCertificates (if there is one), or tries to reuse an anonymous
>   sessions if ClientCertificates is empty.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SslStream, disable session caching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30079379/sslstream-disable-session-caching)