# How to create a new SSL session for every HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, ssl, httpwebrequest

I am using HttpWebRequest to make a requests to a server and want to go through the complete SSL handshake for every request. Will the following code guarantee a new SSL session for every request?

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);
request.CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
```

Comment: HTTP level caching is not related to SSL session handling so I doubt that this could will work. Related instead: [SslStream, disable session caching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30079379/sslstream-disable-session-caching)

Comment: This sounds like something that should be enforced by the server.